# Angular Material: mat-chip inside mat-nav-list focus issue

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a `mat-nav-list` where every `mat-nav-item`has a `(click)`-event attached for navigation.
Inside every item I have some `mat-chips`to display some status info.
When hovering the chip I don't get the pointer cursor from the list item and a click will not trigger the parents event.

How can I make the `mat-chip` not interfere with the cursor and the click event?

```
<mat-nav-list>
    <mat-list-item *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="selectItem(item)">
        {{item.name}}
        <mat-chip-list>
            <mat-chip>Label</mat-chip>
        </mat-chip-list>
    </mat-list-item>
</mat-nav-list>
```

Answer (score 8):

The solution is to disable pointer events on the `chip-list` surrounding the chips:

```
mat-chip-list {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```